# How do you open a mp3 file from the raspberry pi terminal?

Tags: terminal

There is an .mp3 file on my desktop that I would like to open from the command terminal, how do I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Follow the instructions:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install mpg123
mpg123 your-music.mp3
```

If you'd like to play all `.mp3` files of a directory, try this command:

```
mpg123 -vC /your-directory/*.mp3
```

In addition, if you want to play `.wav` files, you can play them by `aplay` command which is part of `alsamixer` package.

```
aplay your-music.wav
```

Comment: Thank you! Is there any way to stop it though, careless whisper is a 5 minute song and I need to do other audio tests...

Comment: I don't understand what you meant. You just want to stop playing a music file which it's last 5 minutes is whisper?

Comment: Nevermind I figured it out (it's ctrl + Z). I just have to run the program several times to test it, and I didn't want to listen to that epic sax solo twenty times.

Comment: @Titan - I don't think M. Rostami is a Wham! fan.

Comment: @GlenYates I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: @Titan - I would suggest you use ctrl + C instead, as ctrl + Z actually just suspends a process. And M. Rostami, Titan's original comment should have rendered _Careless Whisper_ as such to show that it is a title, which would have lessened your chance of confusion, but would not have been necessary were you familiar with Wham! (a musical duo), alas you are not, but no worries.

Comment: @GlenYates Alright, thank you for the clarity.